# how to over come System out memory exception in windows phone 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm Developing windows phone 8 application.

In my application i'm using listbox.I bind listbox value form Webservice. Webservice return json format data's.

The webservice return 40 to 50 records.I bind all the values into listbox.

Everthing work fine.Only on first time run.

For example:-

My project page structure.

```
1.welcomepage
2.Menu Page (it contain six buttons. click on any one particular button it's redirect to sub-menupage)
3.Sub-menupage(Six different page present)
```

In menu page Hotels button is present . if hotels button is clicked it's navigate to Hotels Page.

Now my problem is:-

First Time - welcomepage -> Menu Page -> HotelSubmenu [List of hotels is bind in listbox from webservice]
              Now I goback to Menupage by click on hardwareback button.Now it's in Menu page

If i click again the same Hotels button

It show me the error

```
e.ExceptionObject {system.OutofMemoryException:Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
[System.outofmemoryException]
Data        {system.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HelpLink    null
Hresult     -2147024882
Message     "insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program"
```

My C# code for bind values in listbox

```
public void commonbind()
    {
        try
        {


            this.loadimg.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            loadcheck();

            string common_url = "http://xxxxxx.com/Service/bussinesscitynamesub.php?bcatid=" + businessid + "&cityname=" + cityname + "&bsubid=" + filterid;
            WebClient common_wc = new WebClient();

            common_wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(common_url), UriKind.Relative);
            common_wc.DownloadStringCompleted += common_wc_DownloadStringCompleted;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }


 void common_wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            lbbusiness.Items.Clear();
            var common_val = e.Result;
            if (common_val != "null\n\n\n\n")
            {
                lbopen = 2;
                var jsonconvertvalue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<common_bindclass>>(common_val);

                List<common_bindclass> ls = new List<common_bindclass>();
                ls = jsonconvertvalue;


                for (int i = 0; i < ls.Count; i++)
                {
                    lbbusiness.Items.Add(ls[i]);
                }


                this.loadimg.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                loadcheck();
            }
            else
            {

                if (lbopen == 0)
                {

                    MessageBoxResult resultmsg = MessageBox.Show("No Result present based on your current Location! " + System.Environment.NewLine + "Now showing result without Location based", "Sorry!", MessageBoxButton.OK);

                    if (resultmsg == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                    {
                        lbbusiness.Items.Clear();
                        cityname = "";
                        **commonbind();**
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NavigationService.GoBack();
                    }

                }

                else if (lbopen == 1)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("No Result Present In this Categories");
                    LPfilter.Open();
                }

                else if (lbopen == 2)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("No Result Present In this City");
                    Lpcity.Open();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I try with following method for solve the memory exception

Try1:-
    Clear the List box value before bind every time.

Try2:-

Create the new list every time

```
 common_bindclass bind = new common_bindclass();

 foreach (common_bindclass bind in jsonconvertvalue)
                {
                   lbbusiness.Items.Add(bind);
                }
```

I change the above code to

```
 List<common_bindclass> ls = new List<common_bindclass>();
                ls = jsonconvertvalue;

 for (int i = 0; i < ls.Count; i++)
                {
                    lbbusiness.Items.Add(ls[i]);
                }
```

MY Output For single List

[image]

But my try's not help for me .

any one tell me how to solve it. or alternate way .

How to find in which line the error occur .[I try with break point but it's not help me]

Comment: Try to use GC.Collect() (i think it exists in wp 8) after usering web service. **EDIT** also check the ui. Many times ui creation these problems occur